# How to dynamically render HTML in ASPX without embedding HTML in C# code or C# code in ASPX code?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to loop through a data set on the server-side (not a problem) and dynamically render HTML based on the items in the dataset (super basic stuff). Here's the simplified HTML:

```
<div>item title</div>
<div>item date</div>
<div>item summary</div>
```

I have 10 items being returned on the back-end, so I'd like to write out 10 iterations of the HTML above. I know this is super basic stuff, but I'd like to do this in ASP.NET without 1) embedding HTML in the C# code 2) embedding C# in the ASPX code

Is this possible? What's the best way to do this? I'm also not using MVC, so please keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: It also seems you are generating a list, so I'd suggest using a `ul` with `li` wrapping each title, date & summary group.

Comment: I was just using div's for simplicity. I'm actually using ul/li, I just don't want to embed that HTML in the C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using a `Repeater` for this

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It's a control designed for repeating arbitrary html based on the content of a data source

Comment: I'll look into that. Does Repeater have to use a table? If so, that wouldn't be an option for me.

Comment: It does not depend on a table. It works with any html

Comment: Just used it. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!